# How to preview PBF query results in the browser debugger?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, debugging, browser

Working with ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript, I want a quick preview (in the browser debugger) of the results of a query. For example, when clicking on a polygon in the [PopupTemplate sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-popuptemplate/live/), the Network tab shows the results of the query:

[image: query results in the debugger]

Because the ArcGIS SDK uses the PBF format, the Preview results are not human-readable.

To interpret the results, I need to:

- copy the [query URL](https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/arcgis/rest/services/ACS_Marital_Status_Boundaries/FeatureServer/2/query?f=pbf&objectIds=49481&outFields=B12001_calc_numDivorcedE%2CB12001_calc_numMarriedE%2CB12001_calc_numNeverE%2CB12001_calc_pctMarriedE%2CCounty%2CNAME%2COBJECTID&outSR=102100&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&where=1%3D1)
- paste into a new browser window (but don't hit Enter)
- replace the format parameter `&f=pbf` with `&f=html` or `&f=json`

Now it is possible to view the results in human-readable format:

[image: query results]

Are there any alternate approaches, eg browser plugins, which improve upon this workaround?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/rowanwins/arcgis-pbf-parser. Haven't tried it myself, but it might work.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it looks like that's not a browser plugin but instead a JS component

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such browser plugin. The only solution would be then to catch pbf in the code, parse it with JS parser and display it with the console.log.